# Error at calling a method to draw text in NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

And the next noob question is....I have to draw a lot of text into my view and thought it was a good idea to write a method that makes that easier. This code is in my view:

```
- (void)drawText: (NSString*) tdString : (NSString*) schrift : (unsigned char) r : (unsigned char) g : (unsigned char) b :
                (int) tsize : (int) xpos : (int) ypos;
{
NSPoint textPoint = NSMakePoint(xpos, ypos);
NSMutableDictionary *textAttrib = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[textAttrib setObject:[NSFont fontWithName:schrift size:tsize] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[textAttrib setObject:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:(r/255.0f) green:(g/255.0f) blue:(b/255.0f) alpha:1.0]forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[tdString drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:textAttrib];
}

- (void)drawBPM
{
NSString *bpmString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", bpm];
NSString *tbpmString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mbpm];

if (bpm < 100){             drawText(bpmString,@"Helvetica Light", 140, 140, 140, 36, 100, 100);
}
if (bpm > 99 && bpm < 110){ drawText(bpmString,@"Helvetica Light", 140, 140, 140, 36, 100, 100);
}
if (bpm > 109 && bpm < 200){drawText(bpmString,@"Helvetica Light", 140, 140, 140, 36, 100, 100);
}
if (bpm > 199){             drawText(bpmString,@"Helvetica Light", 140, 140, 140, 36, 100, 100);
}
}
```

In the editor I get the warning "Implicit declaration of function 'drawText' is invalid in C99". At run I get an error : "Symbols not found for architecture x86_64
Linker command failed with exit code 1". It's obvious that this must be asked before but I just can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  warning "Implicit declaration of function 'drawText' is invalid in C99" is because you haven't *declared* the method in your `@interface`.

You have also defined the method incorrectly, it should be (newlines optional, but a good idea):

```
- (void)drawText:(NSString*)tdString
         schrift:(NSString*)schrift
               r:(unsigned char)r
               g:(unsigned char)g
               b:(unsigned char)b
           tsize:(int)tsize
            xpos:(int)xpos
            ypos:(int)ypos;
```

(note that you should be using `CGFloat` for colours and positions rather than integers).

Then it needs to be called as an Objective-C method, not a C method:

```
[self drawText:bpmString
       schrift:@"Helvetica Light"
             r:140
             g:140
             b:140
         tsize:36
          xpos:100
          ypos:100];
```

And finally, you are calling these methods from inside `[NSView drawRect:]` aren't you?

Comment: Ok, I have other methods there also not declared and they work, is it because of the parameters? And yes, I'm calling these methods from inside [NSView drawRect:]

Comment: @fw2601 Yes, actually I think the warning is because you are calling the method as if it's a C method, which wasn't declared.  Perform the fixes I mention as you should be OK.